# How to commit a change with both "message" and "description" from the command line?

Tags: git, github

I can push commits to GitHub via `git` (on the command line, not the Mac app).

When I push commits directly from the GitHub web interface (e.g. quickly fixing a typo), I have the chance to "comment" the commit, and GitHub gives me a commit *title* and a commit *description*. I find this very useful.

Still, when I `git push` from the local machine, `git` opens my default editor: so I write the commit comment, and then GitHub automatically divides it into title and "body". Is there a way to pretty comment commits from terminal too?

Comment: It is well described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645586/6839738

Answer (score 1241, accepted):

There is also another straight and more clear way

```
git commit -m "Title" -m "Description ..........";
```

Comment: Well, a nice hack, but I prefer [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36427485/3810038) because it provides me a way to type a long description with newlines, with ease.

Comment: I do as well ^ But I feel if you're doing commit after commit you don't want to open the VIM every time. Can you add `\n` into the description doing it this way? E.g `git commit -m "Title" -m "Description....\nNew line....\nAnother new line`

Comment: why not @James111

Comment: Adding `\n` in the description to add a line break doesn't work. Refer [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064563/add-line-break-to-git-commit-m-from-the-command-line).

Comment: @James111 If you're going to use \n you need to put it inside of `$''` like this: `$'test\ntext'`

Comment: for those using **github desktop** : fwiw, I noticed that you need **2 new lines** to make the description appear as such

Comment: @James111 u mean `git commit -m "$'- searchScreen background added \n - SearchBar color matched'"` ??

Comment: @YashJadhav no, it should be used as `git commit -m 'Title' -m $'Description line 1\nline 2\nline 3 ......'`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16122262/9140224)

Comment: @JohnRed I think this method is a better example to set for most users coming across this, to help enforce the 50 / 70 rule for git commits: Max 50 characters for message and max 70 for descriptions. This helps enforce users to be concise for others with their commits.

Answer (score 611):

Use the `git commit` command without any flags. The configured editor will open (Vim in this case):

[image]

To start typing press the <kbd>INSERT</kbd> key on your keyboard, then in insert mode create a better commit with description how do you want. For example:

[image]

Once you have written all that you need, to returns to git, first you should exit insert mode, for that press <kbd>ESC</kbd>. Now close the Vim editor with save changes by typing on the keyboard `:wq` (w - write, q - quit):

[image]

and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

On GitHub this commit will looks like this:

[image]

As a commit editor you can use [**VS Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com):

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

From VS Code docs website: **[VS Code as Git editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_vs-code-as-git-editor)**

Gif demonstration: [image]

Comment: I think theres a little change while saving your commit just press ctrl+x it will prompt you to save by pressing y and then hit enter and git push should do the job

Comment: `without any flags` - well, there are some flags you do can use, such as `--all` `--no-verify` and more.. (Haven't check but probably all except `-m`)

Answer (score 86):

```
git commit -a -m "Your commit message here"
```

will quickly commit all changes with the commit message. Git commit "title" and "description" (as you call them) are nothing more than just the first line, and the rest of the lines in the commit message, usually separated by a blank line, by convention. So using this command will just commit the "title" and no description.

If you want to commit a longer message, you can do that, [but it depends on which shell you use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064563/add-line-break-to-git-commit-m-from-command-line).

In bash the quick way would be:

```
git commit -a -m $'Commit title\n\nRest of commit message...'
```

Comment: With `a` flag, git will stage all modified files and that is not what is usually desired. I would suggest removing `a` flag from your example.

Comment: @HarisMuzaffar I don't know about you, but that IS the behaviour that's "usually desired" in my workflow and I just learned about this flag because of this answer. :P

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to improve the commit message with header and body after you created the commit, you can [reword](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/#commands-available-while-rebasing) it. This approach is more useful because you know what the code does only after you wrote it.

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

Then, your commits will appear:

```
pick e152ce2 Update framework
pick ffcf91e Some magic
pick fa672e1 Update comments
```

Select the commit you want to reword and save.

```
pick e152ce2 Update framework
reword ffcf91e Some magic
pick fa672e1 Update comments
```

Now, you have the opportunity to add header and body, where the first line will be the header.

```
Create perpetuum mobile

Redesign laws of physics with a pinch of imagination. Open a wormhole in 23 dimensions. Add protection to avoid high instability.
```

Comment: Your approach certainly works, but only in quite specific case. You can't do this if you already pushed your commits (without some dark magic :) ), and more importantly, it doesn't trully fit the OP's described situation.