# Close Gitlab issue via commit

Tags: gitlab

I spend my day doing this:

1. Read an issue on a Gitlab-powered issue tracker,
2. Fix the issue,
3. Commit and push to the same Gitlab-powered Git server,
4. Mark the issue as closed.

To remove the 4th step, how can I close the issue automatically when committing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Commit and push using this syntax:

```
git commit -m "Sort more efficiently" -m "Closes #843"
git push
```

This will commit and close the issue.
Note that unlike Github a single `-m` will not work.
The following will appear on the issue page:

[image]

References:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#closing-issues-automatically
- [How to commit a change with both "message" and "description" from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122234/how-to-commit-a-change-with-both-message-and-description-from-the-command-line)

Comment: How do you close an issue on a subgroup, called e.g. backlog? `git commit -m "Sort more efficiently" -m "Closes backlog#843"`

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it says this only works on the default branch. Is there any way to have this work on, for example, the `develop` branch?

Comment: Very interesting that one cannot do both. Quite counterintuitive. I am looking forward to a change in this behaviour since many people either come from GitHub or work in parallel with both GitHub and GitLab.

Answer (score 12):

According to [this link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#closing-issues-automatically) from gitlab, you will be able to do that with a variety of words such as "fixes" or "closes". It does not need to be in a seperate line.

So you could have the following message:

`Fixes #20. I had to replace "foo" with "bar".`

And that will close issue #20.