# How to separate title from body in a git commit message using Notepad++?

Tags: git, version-control, notepad++, commit, git-commit

I am using `git` on windows and when I use the `commit` command in the command prompt, my Notepad++ opens up and asks me to put in a commit message as follows:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

This is great, but I want to be able to separate the message title from its body. When I write my commit message above the #'s, it is sent as if I used the `commit -m` command, that is, it contains only a title.

Can someone suggest the proper way to be able to separate the title from the body in a commit message using Notepad++?

**Edit**: this question is different from other questions about separating body from title in commit messages, because the other questions ask how to do it from the command line, whereas I ask how to do it with Notepad++
.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to commit a change with both "message" and "description" from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122234/how-to-commit-a-change-with-both-message-and-description-from-the-command-li)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add your title+body separated by two line breaks like this:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Title of the commit message

Body of the commit message (description)
```

And press 'save' in notepad++ and close the window.

Answer (score 6):

The subject and the body are separated by the first blank line after the subject. So you have several options to write a message that has a subject and a body.

```
git commit -m 'foo

bar'
```

or

```
git commit -m 'foo' -m 'bar'
```

or
in the editor,

```
foo

bar
#comment...
#comment...
#comment...
```

Answer (score 1):

For separating title from body write your commit message title in one line then, press enter and then write a brief description of the commit in the next line it will automatically be separated from the title then save and push 
and git commit -m will be title use notepad for descriptions.

`#` will be treated as commit and will not appear in the commit message.