# Extended commit description message in android studio

Tags: git, android-studio, git-commit

Is there a way to add the **extended commit description message** in the android studio (like the GitHub website provide) using the IDE not via command line, I researched on this and I didn't found anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can always [reword (in Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49788866/6309) a commit you have just made, adding new lines to your commit message, making it an extended description.

Second, check if, as [in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51316392/6309), all you need to do is:

> type title, then double-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and description

Similar to what [you see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427485/6309), but [done in the Android Studio commit message box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41285301/6309):

[image: Android Studio Commit message input box]

A multiple lines commit message should be an extended commit description