# how to write a commit description in source control VScode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In the GitHub Desktop, I can write an indefinite count of lines in the description field for my commit, and this field is **distinguished from the commit message**:

[image]

I know that I can do [the same thing in the git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22909204/11747148) using:

```
git commit -m "Title" -m "Description ..........";
```

Now I wonder if I can do the same in the Source Control VSCode.
There's a field in a source control tab as the following but I don't know if it's the title of the commit (commit message) or the description:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## 1. First way

I found out that the first line represents the commit message, and the lines after representing the description:
[image]

Result in the GitHub:
[image]

## 2. Second way

This can be done in another way if I leave the message field (highlighted with green in the following image) empty and hit the commit button:
[image]

Then a new tab shows up with the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` name, and I can add the commit message and the description there:
[image]

The result in the GitHub after pushing would be the following:
[image]