# Is there a way to git commit --fixup=amend while changing the commit message non-interactively?

Tags: git, git-commit

I want to squash some commit through scripting using `git commit --fixup`, but I have got stuck on the fact that the `-m` switch for messages cannot be used with `--fixup:amend`.

```
$ git commit --fixup=amend::/'Upgrade to foo' -m "Upgrade to bar"
fatal: options '-m' and '--fixup:amend' cannot be used together
```

(I would later `git rebase --autosquash <some-much-earlier-commit>` to squash them all together if I could get that far)

I could use the plain `--fixup` without `amend` but then I cannot change the commit message. Without the `-m` message, the editor opens for editing the commit message, so this cannot be done through scripting.

I understand that these are "porcelain" commands, but as I am doing this through scripting, I was wondering if there is still a way of doing the equivalent of `git commit --fixup=amend` while still changing the commit message non-interactively using "plumbing" commands?

Comment: You might be looking for `git commit-tree`.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the commit message non-interactively"? Will you show what the before and after states of your git history that you want to have?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Scripting, so not by editing the message in $EDITOR. Somehow edit the message without `-m`

Comment: ok, I think I understand that. I think this is an XY Problem where you have a partial solution to solve a problem. It will be more clear if you can create an example. I recommend that you create a git history. Then show what you want the result to be after you run this `git commit` command.

Comment: This sounds like you are looking for `git commit --amend -m 'the new message'`. `git commit --fixup=amend:commit` is intended to queue a fixup commit to be processed by `git rebase -i --autosquash` later. It does not update a commit message at all.

Comment: @j6t I think you are getting confused with straight `--fixup`, as `--fixup=amend` does allow the message to be changed - that's the difference between the two. It's just that it needs to be done interactively in $EDITOR, instead of on the command line with `-m` which is the problem I am facing here. `git commit --amend -m "message"` only changes the commit of the last commit, and doesn't do anything other than that.

Comment: Please mention in the question if and how you invoke `git rebase` after using `git commit --fixup`.

Comment: @j6t Okay, I have added that, but I can't see how it helps. (I actually just rebase as I have rebase to to autosquash in git config)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can totally use **git commit --fixup=amend** to fix up and amend a commit message without having to interactively input anything. All you have to do is use the **-C** or **--reuse-message** option along with the old git commit command.

Here's the example command:

```
git commit --fixup=amend -C HEAD --no-edit
```

The **-C** and **--no-edit** parameters specifies the commit to fixup and ensures that the commit message is not opened in an editor, preventing the need for interactive input.

Git will automatically fixup and amend the commit with the new message without requiring you to interactively edit the message.

However, just do note that using **--fixup=amend** modifies the commit history, so use it with caution, especially if the commit has already been pushed to a remote repository.

Comment: "Git will automatically fixup and amend the commit with the new message without requiring you to interactively edit the message." - Thanks, but how does it get the new message?

Comment: "However, just do note that using --fixup=amend modifies the commit history" - Not sure what you mean, as when I do this all that happens is a new commit is made with the !fixup prefix. It's only squashed into the previous commit when with rebase --autosquash?

Comment: also this is just not working: `fatal: Only one of -c/-C/-F/--fixup can be used.` (tested on git 2.34.1)

Answer (score -1):

Git will create a new commit based on your `git commit --fixup=amend:...` command. You can create this commit yourself:

```
git commit -m "amend! <commit hash / old commit message>" -m "new commit message"
```

so for your given example it would be

```
git commit -m "amend! Upgrade to foo" -m "Upgrade to bar"
```

Note: the second `-m` parameter will fill the description. Alternatively when using an editor, you can put the second `-m` argument on the third line:

```
amend! Upgrade to foo

Upgrade to bar
```

See: [How to commit a change with both "message" and "description" from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16122234/6846334)

Comment: I'll try this at some point next time I am in this frame of mind, but I am sceptical. I just can't get my head around it at the moment as I cannot remember what this issue is about.